# How to control Kodi with the command line or media controls?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, dbus, kodi, media-buttons

I am trying to make controlling kodi easier with keyboard shortcuts or from the terminal. Something like how I can control spotify with DBUS or with keyboard shortcuts. I came across [this link](https://kodi.wiki/?title=JSON-RPC_API) but I have no idea how to use JSON.
I am using Kodi 17.6 krypton and Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in RPC api

See the Official documentation : https://kodi.wiki/view/JSON-RPC_API

1. Enable http remote control (kodi system settings)
2. Write some script for your need
3. An exemple : clean video database

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ## Configure your XBMC RPC details here
   XBMC_HOST=192.168.0.200
   XBMC_PORT=80
   XBMC_USER=osmc
   XBMC_PASS=osmc

   function xbmc_req {
   curl -s -i -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$1" http://$XBMC_USER:$XBMC_PASS@$XBMC_HOST:$XBMC_PORT/jsonrpc 
   }

   # Clean
   xbmc_req '{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "VideoLibrary.Clean", "id": "mybash"}';
   ```